# Java constructor with method that creates instance of that object

Tags: java, xml, constructor, xstream

I want to create constructor which takes xml as string and all variables would be fill from that. That xml is created by XStream so I think that something like this would work but don´t know what to add to left side:

```
    public xmlpacket(String xml)
    {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
       .... =  (xmlpacket)xstream.fromXML(xml);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a static method.

```
public static XMLPacket unmarshall(String xml) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

    return (XMLPacket)xstream.fromXML(xml);

}
```

Notice how I renamed your class. Now it adheres to Java Naming Conventions.

Answer (score 1):

If you've created the classes you need and the xstream aliases for the classes then

```
XMLPacket packet = (XMLPacket)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

But you should probably create a method for this and not do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

XStream will create the instance of the object for you. So unless you want to copy all the attributes of the XStream-created packet to the packet you're constructing, it makes no sense to do that in a constructor. Create a factory method instead:

```
public static XmlPacket fromXml(String xml) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    return (XmlPacket) xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```